# Is there any way a Google Chrome extension can increase local storage space?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, local-storage

I think HTML5 local storage can store a maximum of 5MB per domain.  Can a Google Chrome extension specify a domain for an increase in storage?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/6281947/632951

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can only request unlimited space for extension's storage in the manifest, storages that belong to other domains cannot be changed:

```
"permissions": [
  "unlimitedStorage"
],
```

[(more info)](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/dev/manifest.html#permissions)

Comment: Afaik the unlimitedStorage permission doesn't apply to localStorage, only websql and app cache.  Google devs say that localStorage doesn't scale well enough to make it work - http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=58985