# How can I request an increase to the HTML5 localstorage size on iPad, like the FT web app does?

Tags: javascript, ios, html, mobile-website, local-storage

If you open http://app.ft.com (the Financial Times mobile web app), you are prompted to add the app to your "home".

After doing this, when you open the app, you are prompted again to allow the localstoreage database size to be increased up to 50MB.

- How can this be done? Is there some JavaScript API call? Permissions or whatever?
- Is this iPad (iOS?) specific, or does it work on other Webkit browsers?

Comment: don't mix local-storage (key-value storage, 5MB hard limit) with local database storage (sqlite, 5MB and can grow up to 50MB with the right tricks)

Answer (score 37, accepted):

I happen to know something about this ;)

There's no API for requesting an increase in storage size for an existing database.  There is one way to force an increase: write data to the database in such a size that an increase is required, prompting the user.  However, this would be slow *and* there's no way to tell the currently allocated space, so it's not recommended.

Black Frog has part of this correct: the only neat way to do this is to request a very large database when it is opened, for example:

```
openDatabase('databaseName', '1.0', 'My Database', 50*1024*1024, …
```

… to request 50MB of space.

However, when the user first visits the site, you may not want to prompt them about a 50MB limit at once; so you might think that you could ask for 5MB at first, and then later re-open it with 50MB?  Unfortunately, this doesn't work - the second open attempt, with an increased quantity, succeeds silently, not prompting for a size increase and not actually increasing the available size.

The FT app therefore starts off with a 5MB "preview" database, so that the user isn't prompted on first load.  It tries not to exceed this 5MB limit, as any space assigned has to be shared across all databases.

If the user chooses to allow storage of more content, the app then tries to open a database with a different name with 40MB of space (for which the user is prompted to approve 50MB).  This allows 40MB in that database, and 5MB in the original preview database, so neither should fail when inserting rows - as 50MB total is currently the limit on iOS.

All browsers currently handle database space limits differently, so if you're planning cross-platform, test carefully.  Desktop Safari handles it rather nicely, allowing much larger; Chrome doesn't allow any increase at all; etc.  Expect all "HTML5" implementations to differ in strange ways :)

Comment: I've asked a question about the FT app, mind commenting on it?  Thanks

Comment: @Rowan do you know if the 50Mb limit is: domain, device or browser specific? I'm required to store 600Mb of video in a client side DB so investigating a workaround of navigating to different domains then storing 50Mb of video on each.

Comment: @ChristopherGrigg It's domain-specific, and people have used hacks to shard data that way.  In the browser you may get prompted per subdomain...?  However, as of iOS 7 if you get them to save the page to the homescreen before use, I think the limits have been removed (for WebSQL, anyway)... give http://demo.agektmr.com/storage/ a try to test and let us know the results :)

Comment: @Rowan thanks for the info, my tests have shown that it is indeed domain specific and once the user is asked once about the memory limit, it never asks again. I've not managed to get over 50Mb as of yet, seems pretty locked down, however I'm using PouchDB as opposed to WEB SQL directly.

Comment: @Rowan, Isn't this **a Chrome bug** and thus behavior is bound to change eventually in the future?

Answer (score 7):

This database is part of [Web SQL Database](http://www.w3.org/TR/webdatabase/) API, which is not part of HTML5.  Use the following the set the size of your database

```
function prepareDatabase(ready, error) {
    return openDatabase('documents', '1.0', 'Offline document storage', 50*1024*1024, function (db) {
        db.changeVersion('', '1.0', function (t) {
            t.executeSql('CREATE TABLE docids (id, name)');
        }, error);
    });
}
```

[Introducing Web SQL Databases](http://html5doctor.com/introducing-web-sql-databases/) on HTML5 Doctor has a very quick tutorial on how all of this works.

Comment: Isn't Web SQL already dead? The page you link says *"Please beware that as of 18th November the W3C is no longer actively working on the Web SQL Database specification"*

Comment: this answer was post in 2011 :P, so don't expect to keep being true

Answer (score 1):

I just tested with my offline app in iPad 2( iOS 5.1.1) that we do not need to do anything specific inside the app. For e.g., my app has about 18 MB of offline data. When the browser hit URL, browser popped up the message requesting increase in size to 25 MB and I accepted it and all is fine. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It's browser specific. Most have set it to 5MB and some give the option of increasing it through a setting somewhere. Not all browsers offer this though.

Answer (score -1):

Huh — Dive into HTML5 says that [no browser supported this as of February 2011](http://fortuito.us/diveintohtml5/storage.html#limitations), so I guess this might be an iOS 4.3 thing? (iOS 4.3 shipped in March 2011.)

I can’t find any references to it from a quick Google. Apple’s own developer documentation might mention it — I’m not sure if that’s available to non-SDK subscribers though.