# How can I store more that 5MB in HTML 5 local storage

Tags: iphone, ipad, html, sencha-touch, local-storage

I need to write an app to run on iPhone, iPad, Android phones & tablets. WinPhone 7 and desktop browsers would also be nice, but not necessary.  I'm a desktop/Silverlight developer, but it seems this is a job for HTML 5 & javascript. Right?

I'm looking at Sencha touch, jquery, and amplify.js to simplify my life.  My app has to be available in app stores, so I'm looking at PhoneGap to help with that.

The app needs to work offline which means I have need for local storage of about 10 megs. I don't know how to deal with this requirement because all the local storage options seem to top off at 5 megs.

Any ideas about how to deal with this?  (Or any suggestions as to a better approach or libraries?)

Comment: 10 mg in an iphone app is no problem, you can download apps less then 20 mb over 3g any thing bigger needs to be download over WiFi.

Comment: The app is a web app, not really a native app, so i think there's a 5 meg limit.

Comment: Not if he is using Phonegap and talking about the App Store.

Comment: Is the limit 5MB per website or 5MB for all websites total that a user stores local storage information for?

Answer (score 0):

I would try your best to get your app down to less than 5 Mb. This means perhaps compression of some sort before locally storing, perhaps only having the essential features available offline, and optimizing your data such that you can reduce any redundancy. Even after all of this, you are still dependent on whether or not the user's browser allows local storage, and whether it allows 5 Mb of it.

Comment: I think all of the new browsers will give 5 megs of WebStorage of 5 megs, but no more. i can't get the Dictionary that small. I'm hoping someone knows a workaround.

Comment: Perhaps I could use WebSQL Database? Or could I install files with a native app that my web app could somehow access?

Comment: Maybe, but those warnings about no longer being maintained are pretty scary. Are browsers going to support this going forward? Would you be willing to bet your app on it?

Answer (score 0):

As per [an answer on a question earlier today](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6276282/how-can-i-request-an-increase-to-the-html5-localstorage-size-on-ipad-like-the-ft/6278016#6278016), the [Web SQL Database](http://html5doctor.com/introducing-web-sql-databases/) spec is your friend here, at least on iOS 4.3