# How to adapt offline HTML5 app for iPad if requires storing up to 500MB of data?

Tags: ios, html, ipad, safari, local-storage

I've got a current web app that runs in Chrome and Firefox and uses IndexedDB to store data, inlcuding videos as blobs. Safari does not implement IndexedDB, so I would change to using localStorage (is that the only thing available?).

But my understanding is that there's a 50MB limit. Is this true? Are there other options for an HTML5 app on an iPad to store files and data? (The app must be usable offline)

Is there a way to put the video and PDF files directly on the iPad and link to them in the HTML5 app?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6276282/how-can-i-request-an-increase-to-the-html5-localstorage-size-on-ipad-like-the-f

Comment: @MarkM so there's no way to use local db, but what about my second question? Can I load the videos onto the iPad and then access them via the HTML5 app?

Comment: If you are using a webView to display content from a native app then yes you can access local videos from your photo library or documents folder.

Comment: @MarkM Do you mean serving the HTML5 app from within a custom native app? No, I was looking to have this just run in Safari. Does that mean no file access?

Comment: Correct, you are bound to the limits of safari. :-/

Comment: @MarkM Do you know if the storage limit also applies to PhoneGap apps? (Since they also use web storage)

Comment: No it doesn't apply to phoneGap since all they are doing is creating a native iOS app and displaying content in a UIWebView.

Comment: Right, but wouldn't that UIWebView be using Safari as the back end and still have the 50MB limit applied?

Comment: No because the content would be stored locally more than likely and not in safari's cache. A UIWebView is not a full blown copy of safari and does have it's limits (acceleration in anything other than transforms for example).