# HTML5 Localstorage increase limit

Tags: jquery, html, offline

I am currently building a website which will work offline for a user to collect data then once they have a connection to upload to the server.

The problem is, local-storage will only allow 3-4 submissions per batch due to images attached to the data.

Is there any way around this?

Comment: How about IndexedDb / WebSql with BLOB fields?

Comment: Will websql work offline?

Comment: yes. If you dont have that much experience with websql and/or indexed db, i would recommend to check out this library https://github.com/mozilla/localForage

Comment: I've just looked at websql, are you sure it can hold 50mg of data?

Comment: As far as I know, 50MB is the default limit for indexdb. I'm not sure about websql but there are many refs around the web. I recommend you to use indexdb instead of websql. There is a note on several blogs like `Please beware that as of 18th November the W3C is no longer actively working on the Web SQL Database specification.` Anyway..you can usually set a higher limit in your browser options.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/6281947/632951