# requestQuota for localStorage

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, web-storage

Is it possible to request for more `localStorage` (of the Web Storage API) on chrome? 
Can the `requestQuota` method be used with `localStorage`?

PS: Chrome allows me to store upto 5MB before saying 'quota exceeded'.

Comment: I would like to direct you to [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6281947/3565383).

Comment: Thanks but that answer talks about the Web SQL API. I would like to know about the Web Storage API

Comment: Related discussion about `localStorage` limits: https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=58985 "We don't want people to store large amounts of information in LocalStorage.  The API can block a page (and any other pages in your same renderer process) while it loads LocalStorage into memory because it's a synchronous API.  Honestly, we'd just plain not support it if we could, but too many developers/sites rely on it.  So this is the compromise."