# How to increase size of local Storage for sencha app

Tags: android, sencha-touch, local-storage

I am working on an android app, which is developed using Sencha touch 2.4

While storing data locally when the device is off-line.

I need to store some images and some JSON data in the local store, how can I increase the size of local store? If these is any other way to store the data please suggest.

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to increase size of localstorage. It's limited by browsers and usually has 5 MB limit. However, you can try WebSQL databases. You can start here: [How can I request an increase to the HTML5 localstorage size on iPad, like the FT web app does?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6276282/how-can-i-request-an-increase-to-the-html5-localstorage-size-on-ipad-like-the-f)

Another options is to use AppCache API: http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/appcache/beginner/

Also, there are some tools from Sencha: http://www.sencha.com/blog/offline-techniques-sencha-touch/