# localStorage limit in Chrome extension

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, local-storage

I have a couple of questions on use of localStorage in Chrome extensions.

- Is the [5mb storage limit](https://developer.chrome.com/dev/extensions/faq.html#faq-dev-09) per extension?
- Does Chrome use the extension ID to monitor whether an extension conforms to this limit?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5302212/is-there-any-way-a-google-chrome-extension-can-increase-local-storage-space

Comment: Doesn't mention what Chrome uses to monitor whether an extension conforms to the limit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In short: Yes and Yes.

`localStorage` is tied to an origin <sup>[w3 spec: The `localStorage` attribute](http://www.w3.org/TR/webstorage/#dom-localstorage)</sup>, usually the protocol and host part of a resource's URL.

The origin of a Chrome extension is `chrome-extension://EXTENSIONIDHERE`, which implies that the extensionID of a Chrome extension is indeed used to enforce the per-origin storage limits.

You can find a proof of this by visiting your profile directory, and looking in the `Default/Local Storage` directory, which contains several (SQLite) files of the following format:

```
chrome-extension_EXTENSIONIDHERE_0.localstorage
chrome-extension_EXTENSIONIDHERE_0.localstorage-journal
```

Answer (score 1):

- Extension's localStorage is similar to website's localStorage so I guess it'd be 5mb. You can also consider using [chrome.storage](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/storage.html#property-local-QUOTA_BYTES)
- Extension id is the only unique thing to every extension so chrome must use this to conform to this limit.