# Does a Chrome extension have his own localStorage

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, local-storage

I'm creating a Chrome extension that gets the current active textbox and puts a predefined text into it.

I want to use the localStorage, and the question is.
Does a extension have his own localStorage or must it use the LS from the website?

And if the extension does not have his own LS, how can I achieve to save some data on the local computer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer depends on whether the extension is a [*content script*](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts) or not.

If it's a content script, it runs within the page's origin, and so uses the page's `localStorage`.

If it's not a content script, then according to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17628448/157247) to a question about storage limits, yes, your extension gets its own local storage because its origin is `chrome-extension://EXTENSIONIDHERE`. `localStorage` is stored per origin, so your extension will have its own local storage.

As an alternative, as I mentioned in a comment, you can use [`chrome.storage`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/storage) (available to content scripts and non-content scripts alike), which has options for syncing, can store objects rather than just strings, and various other advantages.

Answer (score 0):

Google Chrome released the storage API: http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/storage.html

Question 1: But I want to use the localStorage, and the question is. Does a extension have his own localStorage (I use LS as abbreviation) or must it use the LS from the website Answer: yes Question 2: And if the extension does not have his own LS, how can I achieve to save some data on the local computer? Answer: it has, so it is passed by.

Comment: That's true, but it doesn't answer the question about `localStorage` (which is why I posted it as a comment instead of an answer as you were posting your answer).

Comment: Yes it has its own local storage.
docs: The localStorage object is relative to the "local environment", this means that the localStorage object on http://www.google.com is totally different from the one on http://stackoverflow.com, and obviously is totally different from the one in the background page of your extension.

Comment: But is that, in fact, the origin used by an extension when it accesses `localStorage`? Extensions are an interesting beastie. I mean, I'd certainly *hope* it was separate...

Comment: And the answer to "does it use google.com" appears to be "no," which is not surprising.

Comment: Question 1: But I want to use the localStorage, and the question is. Does a extension have his own localStorage (I use LS as abbreviation) or must it use the LS from the website Answer: yes

Question 2: And if the extension does not have his own LS, how can I achieve to save some data on the local computer? Answer: it has, so it is passed by.

Comment: You meant `update 2012`? chrome.storage is available since Chrome 20 which was released 5 years ago. What kind of answer is this, seriously?